# Ansible: How to skip some empty item when using with_items module?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I wanted to use iptables module with with_items for looping these rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

As you can see, they've different types of source (source address, input interface, output interface) that could possibly cause a problem when using with_item.

Here're my Ansible code

```
- name: Drop packet from loopback IP
  iptables:
    chain: "{{ item.chain }}"
    source: "{{ item.source }}"
    in_interface: "{{ item.in_interface }}"
    out_interface: "{{ item.out_interface }}"
    jump: " {{ item.jump }}"
  with_items:
    - { chain: INPUT, in_interface: lo, jump:  ACCEPT }
    - { chain: OUTPUT, out_interface: lo, jump:  ACCEPT }
    - { chain: INPUT, source: 127.0.0.0/8, jump:  DROP }
```

There're some missing fields in every item.

For e.g. The first one are source and out_interface cause it's obviously has just only in_interface. So, my question is how can I handle that empty fields?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"How can I handle that empty fields?"*

A: Use [default(omit)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) filter. For example

```
- name: Drop packet from loopback IP
  iptables:
    chain: "{{ item.chain }}"
    source: "{{ item.source|default(omit) }}"
    in_interface: "{{ item.in_interface|default(omit) }}"
    out_interface: "{{ item.out_interface|default(omit) }}"
    jump: " {{ item.jump }}"
  with_items:
    - { chain: INPUT, in_interface: lo, jump:  ACCEPT }
    - { chain: OUTPUT, out_interface: lo, jump:  ACCEPT }
    - { chain: INPUT, source: 127.0.0.0/8, jump:  DROP }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, haven't try yet but once I run the playbook, I'll update outputs here.